# Rails ATOM Invalid Encoding Error when using Kramdown for markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, atom-feed, kramdown

I'm attempting to generate an RSS/Atom feed within my application.

At the moment it all works if I pass in the raw markdown but once I use Kramdown I get the following error:

`undefined method 'valid_encoding?' for nil:NilClass`

**index.atom.builder**

```
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title(@user.display_name)
  feed.updated(@ungrouped_digests[0].send_at) if @ungrouped_digests.length > 0

  @ungrouped_digests.each do |post|
    feed.entry(post) do |entry|
      entry.title(post.subject)
      entry.content(render("post", post: post), type: 'html')
      entry.author do |author|
        author.name(@user.full_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**_post.atom.erb**

```
<%= Kramdown::Document.new(post.markdown_body).to_html.html_safe %>
```

If I switch the above to just `<%= post.markdown_body %>` it renders the raw markdown but obviously that's not what I want here.

Comment: Does the fix in [#7302](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/7302) help?